# Getting ListView item ID from its ListAdapter's row ID

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listadapter, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to create a single-choice (e.g., radio button) list of items that are queried from a database. To work with the currently selected row, I need to use the `getCheckedItemPosition()` and `setItemChecked()` methods of ListView.

I have a `ListView` that has a `SimpleCursorAdapter` set on it. When I retrieve the currently selected item, I have its **row ID** from the database, which I need to use to find the appropriate item and manually set it to be selected via the aforementioned methods. In other words, I need to map the status of a row ID to a necessarily monotonic row ID (because the `setItemChecked()` method accepts a position ID, not a database row ID, and in my database I can remove items).

So is there a way I can get a position id from a table row id? I'd rather not resort to doing a search if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: if i got your question right ( i sure hope) I think you should use a KeyValuePair, the key being the row id and the value being the position ID. for keeping count of position you can use a counter and update it everytime a item is added based on your query.

Comment: The thing is, I use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a `Cursor` from an SQLite query. This is all done automatically; that is, I use startManagingCursor(). Is there some way I can intercept when an item is added so that I can create an index (perhaps using a `SparseIntArray`)? Or is my approach to this wrong altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up just creating a simple method that searches through all the items (which are assumed to be in order):

```
/**
 * Since Android apparently provides no way to do this, do a simple binary
 * search for the item position based on its row id.
 * @param adapter    The adapter to use
 * @param row    The rowId to search for
 * @param left
 * @param right
 * @return    Position, or -1 if not found
 */
public int getPositionFromRowId(ListAdapter adapter, long row, int left, int right) {
    if (left > right)
        return -1;
    int middle = (left + right) / 2;
    if (adapter.getItemId(middle) == row)
        return middle;
    if (adapter.getItemId(middle) > row)
        return getPositionFromRowId(adapter, row, left, middle - 1);
    else
        return getPositionFromRowId(adapter, row, middle + 1, right);
}
```

Edit: Use this code by doing something like this:

```
getPositionFromRowId(myListAdapter, row, 0, myListAdapter.getCount());
```