# populate an adapter with the checked items of a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I have an Adapter that poulate my listview ,(A list of books).
my listview contain a checkbox.I wish to show all the checked items in another listview(another activity) once a button is pressed, How can I do this?  I am trying to use the code below. How can I make this happen? 
until now i arrived to show in a toast the number of items in listview,i make a toast when i check or unchecked an item to show her position.i want to know all the positions of the checked items to be the new items of in other listview.And here the code of the Adapter:

```
public  class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{


    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    private ArrayList<Boolean> status_mag = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    public MyAdapter(Activity a,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++){status_mag.add(false);}
     }


    public ArrayList<Boolean> getStauts_mag(){
        return status_mag;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }




    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(vi == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_megashore_mag, parent, false);
        }
        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
        TextView price = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.prix); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
        TextView catg = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.catg_mag);
        CheckBox acheter_mag = (CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAchete_mag);
        HashMap<String, String> mag = new HashMap<String, String>();

        mag = data.get(position);
        title.setText(mag.get(MainMagazines.KEY_TITLE));
        price.setText(mag.get(MainMagazines.KEY_PRICE));
        catg.setText(mag.get(MainMagazines.KEY_CATG));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(mag.get(MainMagazines.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);

        acheter_mag.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (isChecked) {
                    status_mag.set(position, true);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cheked" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    status_mag.set(position, false);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uncheked" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


            }


        });
        acheter_mag.setChecked(status_mag.get(position));
        return vi;

    }


}
```

here the code in main class,button that try to show the SUM of the checked items.

```
final MyAdapter adapter_mag=new MyAdapter(this, booksList);


    getListView().setAdapter(adapter_mag);
    taille_mag=adapter_mag.getCount();
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);




checkitems=(Button)findViewById(R.id.to_favoris);
    checkitems.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i=1;i<=taille_mag;i++){if (adapter_mag.status_mag.get(i)==true){toast_somme+=1;}}
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "la somme de checked items" + toast_somme,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

please help me and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current setup, simply loop through `status_mag` to check if this index is checked. If so save it in a new List and bind this to your new ListView.

Alternatively if the root layout in `list_row_megashore_mag.xml` implements Checkable you can call [`getCheckedItemPositions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPositions%28%29) to fetch a SparseBooleanArray of the checked rows automatically.

Comment: Also note if you need to get the IDs rather than positions then you may have to use this code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6654119/832776

Comment: The ids are very useful for CursorAdapters or other non-position  derived indices, but here the id is at best an alias for the position.

Comment: Oh true - I did not notice the `ArrayList` - indeed in this case IDs are irrelevant.

Comment: thanks for all of you.

I arrived a little to make my target.

i got this in the toast, all the items checked but it shows all them objects:
**{cat_liv=technologie,id_liv=12-23,prix_liv=23,pic_liv=http://192.168.1.100/prg_java111.png,titre_liv=java pour tout le monde}**

**{cat_liv=technologie,id_liv=34-13,prix_liv=100,pic_liv=http://192.168.1.100/image27.png,titre_liv=Python}**

so how can i just take the value of **prix_liv** ??

Comment: i'm so happy 
finally i make it,it was a simple solution but ididn't see it in the good time.so i added a method in the adapter:
** public String get_prix(int position){
   
   return data.get(position).get(KEY_PRICE);
   
  }**
and it run 100% :))
thank you so much